# Crash for lvalue reference binding to return-by-value?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

MSVC is accepting this snippet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string retstr() {
 return std::string("HelloWorld");   
}

void callFunc(std::string& ref) {
 std::cout << ref;   
}

int main()
{
    callFunc(retstr());
}
```

for some backward compatibility reason.

Now.. I'm getting some crashes in a DLL in a function which works exactly like this snippet above: the compiler didn't warn me of having a lvalue reference binding to a ret-by-value thingy.

My question is: this is probably not standard but could it cause a program crash (access violation to be precise)?

Comment: It is definitely not standard.

Comment: As you say, it's not standard, so who knows? But it should not. You may have to inspect the assembly. Also, you may have a DLL boundary issue if those calls are across the DLL boundary.

Comment: @SebastianRedl they are not, they're inside the same C++ DLL which has an extern C interface and gets called by C modules... *sigh*.. what a mess..

Comment: It's unlikely to cause crashes. It's should behave the same as passing by const reference and then casting away constness.

Comment: It doesn't crash on my PC with VS2013 Update 4. I don't have VS2015 so I can't try it there. Which version of VS do you use?

Comment: @MarianSpanik 2015 update1. This snippet won't crash but I wanted to know if the DLL crash (which I can't debug since it's loaded by a C program on XP) could be caused by this

Answer (score 2):

The code as written is fine regarding lifetimes, since the temporary value `retstr()` lives until the end of the full-expression, so it lives as long as the function call.

The fact that MSVC allows binding a lvalue reference to an rvalue does not change that. As always, you have to make sure that `callFunc` does not store references into the string beyond the duration of the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Binding non constant reference to "rvalue" should definitely be  flagged by the compiler .However if compiler is not flagging it ( as in your case ) , it would be problematic at run time(may crash also) .

```
void callFunc(std::string& ref) {
 std::cout << ref;   //what to display?? if temporary is referenced. 
}

int main()
{
    callFunc(retstr()); //would return temporary which will be lost       immidiately.
}
```

In your example temporary is being reference which unfortunately was not flagged by the compiler .Now , when this reference (ref) is utilized , it may crash as it is pointing to something which lost .

I would like to share few points which may be useful .

- If you implement only

  - void foo(X&); 
    without void foo(X&&), the behavior is as in C++98: foo() can be called for lvalues but not for rvalues.
- If you implement only

  - void foo(const X&); 
    without void foo(X&&), the behavior is as in C++98: foo() can be called for lvalues as well as  for rvalues.
- If you implement

  - void foo(X&);
  - void foo(X&&);
  - or void foo(const X&);
  - void foo(X&&);
    you can distinguish between dealing with rvalues and lvalues. The version for rvalues is allowed to and should provide move semantics. Thus, it can steal the internal state and resources of the passed argument. 
    last one is supported in c++11 only .

Comment: The temporary is not "lost immediately", it lives until the end of the full-expression (i.e. the semicolon).

Comment: I hope you read complete post .I just meant , in the specific example temporary would be lost by the time callFunc() function is called .I hope that makes sense .

Comment: But that's not true. In the code you wrote, the temporary lives until after the call of `callFunc` completes.

Comment: You are absolutely wrong .You need a basic c++ book .Please refer some .