# Passing temporary object as a reference to an abstract to a constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm a bit rusty on my C++ and have run into a bit of a snag.

I have a class, in the example `user` which takes a reference to an abstract class for its constructor. Ideally, I'd like for the class to support the following syntax:

```
User u( Sub("") );
u.work();
```

I have an abstract class `super` with a base class called `sub`. The `user` class takes a reference to super in its constructor. At runtime, `user` is passed a temporary reference to `sub`.

When `u.work()` is called I get an exception - because the temporary has been deconstructed. (Oddly enough I get a different behaviour if I remove the destructors on `super` and `sub`).

Example code is below!

Is there a way to fix this problem?

I know there are lots of ways if I accept to change the signature and change the syntax at the call site, but I'd prefer to hold on to the calling signature:

```
User u( Sub("") );
u.work();
```

Example code

```
class Super {
public:
    Super()
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    };

    virtual ~Super()
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void func() = 0;
};

class Sub : public Super
{
public:
    Sub(char* name) :
        name_(name)
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    };

    virtual ~Sub()
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void func()
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    char* name_;
};

class User
{
public:
    User(Super& s) :
        super_(s)
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    ~User()
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    void work()
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        super_.func();
    }

    Super& super_;
};

int main()
{
    User u( Sub("") );
    u.work();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code isn't valid C++ and shouldn't even compile on a proper compiler. If you are using Microsoft, I am very sorry.

Comment: You can't have an rvalue reference and use it for an lvalue reference. Overload your move constructor if you want that.

Comment: The code doesn't compile. why are you using (lval) reference ?

Comment: MSVC came up [recently](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34286871), too. I guess there does exist a lot of code in the wild that abuses this extension... :-(

Comment: `char* name_;` is another red flag. consider using `std::string`

Comment: Yes, I'm using MSVC.
Yes, It does compile and execute - at least on my machine
re: char* name_ (this is just sample code illustrating my problem) Another alternative would have been to remove the char pointer and go for 'User u( (Sub()) );

Comment: I did try an implementation where I overloaded the move constructur, but unfortunately it was never invoked.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, it does appear to be a very similar issue to the one you mention. Now the question is how do I get MSVC to flag an error on this code.

Comment: @Anton: I believe nowadays you can rig Visual Studio up to use Clang as a compiler :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lifetime of a temporary object like your `Sub("")` ends at the end of the full-expression in which it appears, i.e. at the semicolon.

C++ doesn't allow you to bind such temporary objects to mutable references, but Microsoft's compiler does allow that. Nonetheless, initializing a class member reference from such a temporary value immediately produces a dangling reference, which you must never ever use again; evaluating it outside the constructor body results in undefined behaviour.

The way to fix this is to not store references in your class!

For example, if you wanted ownership of a polymorphic value, you could use a unique pointer:

```
 #include <memory>

 class User
 {
    std::unique_ptr<Super> s_;

 public:
    User(std::unique_ptr<Super> s) : s_(std::move(s)) {}

    void work() { s_->func(); }
 };
```

```
 User u(std::make_unique<Sub>("Hello"));
 u.work();
```

Comment: I never knew you could directly use `->` with a `std::unique_ptr` without having to call `get()`, interesting.

Comment: @JameyD: It wouldn't be a very "smart" pointer if you couldn't, would it :-) It'd be more like "a thing with a get function"...

Answer (score 1):

The difference you are seeing between various attempts are all just accidents within undefined behavior.  The structure of `Super` and `Sub` is just a distraction.

You can't keep a reference to a temporary.

```
    User(Super& s) :
        super_(s)
...
    Super& super_;
```

The reference passed in to initialize `super_` must be to an object that lasts at least as long as `super_` can be used.

> I know there are lots of ways if I accept to change the signature and
>   change the syntax at the call site, but I'd prefer to hold on to the
>   calling signature:

You are pretty far from any valid design.  But if you really want to pass, then keep, a polymorphic temp object that way, you could put a virtual clone method into `Super` to support something like:

```
    User(Super& s) :
        super_(s.clone())
...
    std::unique_ptr<Super> super_;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the ownership of the Sub(). Currently you create it, take the reference of it, and just after that it gets destructed.

A proper way may be to pass a pointer to Sub to User, and let User take ownership, keeping the Sub until it no longer needs the Sub. This may look like:

```
class User
{
     Super *super_;
public:
     User(Super *super)
        : super_(super)
     {
     }
     ~User()
     {
        delete super_;
     }
 };


User u( new Sub("") );
```

Comment: You shouldn't suggest using raw pointers when the OP has access to C++11.